# HTTP/2 pushes on AWS API Gateway + Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-api-gateway, http2

Is it possible to run HTTP/2 pushes with [aws-serverless-express](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express)?

As far as I know, AWS API gateway supports HTTP/2 (verified with https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test). Unfortunately, I can't find any example of HTTP/2 pushes under node.js app deployed on lambda.

The only example which I found is Node.js app which supports HTTP/2:
https://github.com/azat-co/http2-node-server-push

Any tips? Solutions? Is it even possible?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Incoming requests to API Gateway are HTTP2 compatible, but requests from API Gateway to your Lambda function will not be HTTP2. Your function code does not need to support HTTP2.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: @RobertoAndrade - yes. (as of September 2018)

Comment: Wrong. it was possible in 16.  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-http2-support-for-cloudfront/

Comment: Updating answer now. ALB and CloudFront both support HTTP2 at present. This means that incoming requests to API Gateway are HTTP2 compatible.

Comment: This does not answer the question about support for the “push” feature of the HTTP/2 protocol.